# My Navbar looks terrible in IE8. It's literally just the links, there's not styling happening at all

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have added the CSS below. The site looks fine in Chrome, Opera, and Firefox    but the nav looks awful in IE. There is absolutely no styling going on at all and it looks terrible. I've added in a html5shim also to my html.

```
/* NAV BAR */
#nav_bar {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index: 1;
background: url(../images/header-fade.gif) repeat-x;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#nav_bar nav {
border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

    #nav_bar nav a {
display: inline-block;
width: 23%;
margin: 0;
padding: 22px 0;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: black;
text-align: center;
border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
text-decoration: none;
font: 20px "Trebuchet MS", Arial, sans-serif;
    }
```

Comment: Want to setup a jsfiddle or something? We have no html here so can't even begin to help...

Comment: Have you checked to see what document mode IE is in?

Comment: We need to view the page in order to see the problem.

Comment: Can you post your html or a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AGA77/

Comment: alderneybunkerparties.co.uk is the website. I have included a shiv so the html5 works but still not working?

Comment: IE8 doesn't read inline-block. Try adding `*display: inline; zoom: 1;`. That's an inline-block hack for ie8 (includes the asterisk).

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your HTML you are using the HTML5 `nav` element.

IE8 does not recognize semantic HTML5 elements like `nav`, `header`, `footer`, `article`, `section` and so forth, so you either need to change it to an HTML4 element (`div` or `ul` or similar) **OR** add a Javascript polyfill like Modernizr or HTML5Shim to add HTML5 element compatibility to older versions of IE.

- [**HTML5Shim**](https://code.google.com/p/html5shim/)
- [**Modernizr**](http://modernizr.com/)

For example, in your `<head>`:

```
<!-- html5.js -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: I do have a shim added, it has been from the start but it doesn't appear to do anything?

Comment: @user1663396 Can't help you without seeing more code. I updated my post to include the shim I use which is pulled from google CDN.

Comment: I'm fairly new to this so I have probably messed a few things up.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to see how the CSS rules are applied to the elements in the F12 tools? They can really help you see what rules and styles are actually being applied and you can adjust them in the tool to see how it will affect your layout.